# function in child component can't setState in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react for the project. Here is my code for parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deleteConfirm: false
    };
  }

  onDelete = pass => {
    this.setState({ deleteConfirm: false });
    if (pass === true) {
      const { menu, onDelete, restaurantId } = this.props;
      //onDelete(menu.id, restaurantId);
    }
  };

  openDiag() {
    this.setState({ deleteConfirm: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          className={classes.button}
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={this.openDiag.bind(this)}
        >
          Delete
          {this.state.deleteConfirm ? (
            <Child onDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)} />
          ) : null}
          <Delete className={classes.rightIcon} />
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The parent component has state called deleteConfirm, If I press Delete button, deleteConfirm is set to true and the child component is rendered. The function OnDelete passes to child component,
the child component is a Material Ui Dialog which is used to confirm the delete action. Here is the code:

```
class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    open: true
  };

  handleClose = (e, confirm) => {
    const { onDelete } = this.props;
    if (confirm === true) {
      onDelete(true);
    } else {
      onDelete(false);
    }
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={e => this.handleClose(e, false)}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={e => this.handleClose(e, false)} 
              color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={e => this.handleClose(e, true)}
              color="primary"
              autoFocus
            >
              Confirm
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I press the cancel button, the delete action is cancelled and the parent function onDelete is called. the deleteConfirm in parent component should be set to false. However, the state is always true and I can't change it. I am greatly appreciated for anybody who would like to help me. Thanks!

Comment: is this your exact code? your `Parent` class' `render` function is not returning anything

Comment: also... consider using prettier to format your code... it's not formatted very well right now.. https://prettier.io/

Comment: @azium   Sorry about the formatting. I have fixed it. I just picked up some main part of my code. The Parenet class render the <div> in my initial one.

Comment: thanks that looks much better. I have a suspicion that because your `Child` is INSIDE the `Button` that the event is propagating and triggering your surrounding button `onClick` which opens the modal. what if you added `e.stopPropagation()` inside `handleClose` ?

Comment: alternatively, you could move `Child` so that it's next to `Button` not inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic [Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) mistake. You embedded a click handler inside another click handler which reversed the logic of the inner one.

Use [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your inner handler or rearrange your elements such that they are not nested within one another:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          className={classes.button}
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={this.openDiag.bind(this)}
        >
          Delete
          <Delete className={classes.rightIcon} />
        </Button>

        {this.state.deleteConfirm ? (
          <Child onDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)} />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
```